# Every time I click an ico sphere appears

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have no idea what I clicked but every time I click on the screen an ico sphere appears. I don't want this. How do I get rid of it??

Comment: What do you meant "ico sphere". Please, provide some screenshot!

Comment: Maybe it's the 3D Cursor gizmo?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally added a shortcut to add icosphere (which is called by mouse click)...? Something similar happened to me once...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.8 and if you are referring to the 3D Cursor, you can hide it in Overlays > 3D Cursor (uncheck).

[image]

[image]